# Two kind of equations involving natural log and exponentiation

Tags: closed-form, transcendental-equations, lambert-w

I know how to solve equations using Lambert's W function like

$xe^x=k$

or

$e^x+x=k$

But how can I solve this two kinds of equations involving natural log ?

$e^x \ln(x)=k$

and

$e^x+\ln(x)=k$

I can't figure how to rewrite them in one way where I can apply $W$

Comment: I don't think you can get an explicit solution. Probably, only numerical methods would do the job (easily).

Comment: Yes, @ClaudeLeibovici but I'm interested in closed-forms involving only special functions, they are too easy to be solved with approximations.

Comment: They would be very special functions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, I give an answer for solutions in the reals.

**a)**

$$e^x\ln(x)=k$$
$x\to e^t$:
$$te^{e^t}=k$$

This equation is an equation of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). It's an equation in dependence of $t$ and $e^{e^t}$, algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$. Because the terms $t,e^{e^t}$ are algebraically independent, we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $t$ by only elementary operations (means elementary functions).
I don't know if the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

Your equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W but in terms of Hyper Lambert W:

$$G(1;t)=k$$
$$t=HW(1;k)$$
$$x=e^{HW(1;k)}$$

see also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315204/expressions-for-the-inverse-function-of-fx-lnxex

**b)**

$$e^x+\ln(x)=k$$
$$e^x=k-\ln(x)$$
$$e^{e^x}=e^{k-\ln(x)}$$
$$e^{e^x}=\frac{e^k}{x}$$
$$xe^{e^x}=e^k$$

This equation is an equation of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). It's an equation in dependence of $x$ and $e^{e^x}$, algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$. Because the terms $x,e^{e^x}$ are algebraically independent, we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by only elementary operations (means elementary functions).
I don't know if the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

Your equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W but in terms of Hyper Lambert W:

$$G(1;x)=e^k$$
$$x=HW(1;e^k)$$
$\ $

So we have closed forms for $x$, and the representations of Hyper Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

Answer (score 4):

If you place $z=\ln(x)$ the equation can be rewritten as:

$$z=k-e^{e^z}$$

Applying lagrange inversion you will find:

$$z=k+\sum_{n=1} \frac{ (-1)^n}{n!} \left[\left(\frac{d}{du}\right)^{n -1}e^{ne^u}\right]_{u=k}$$

now remembering the Rodrigues representation of Touchard polynomials:
( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials )

$$T_n(u)=e^{-e^{u}} \left(\frac{d}{du}\right)^n  e^{e^{u}} $$

you can find a **formal** solution:

$$z(k)=k+\sum_{n=1} \frac{ (-1)^n}{n!}  e^{ne^k} T_{n-1}(k+\ln(n))$$

Therefore replacing $z=\ln(x)$ we find:

$$\ln(x(k))=k+\sum_{n=1} \frac{ (-1)^n}{n!}  e^{ne^k} T_{n-1}(k+\ln(n))$$

If a link with Lambert W function or its one parameter generalization exists I don't know.

**References**
For details about transcendental equations which can be solved by Lagrange series of mixed exponential/hypergeometric polynomials (that is to say transseries) obtained by suitable Rodrigues formulas see:

"Generalization of Lambert W function, Bessel polynomials and transcendental equations" Giorgio Mugnaini

http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00138 (pdf: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00138v3 )