# How to solve $x^{y^z}=z$

Tags: lambert-w, power-towers

Initially I isolated the y in $x^y=y$, but I just wanted to expand the infinite power tower to two letters in the tower, but I can't solve for z in the equation $x^{y^z}=z$. I tried to use Lambert W Function but I can't get the form $ze^{z}$ or something like this. I will be thankful if someone help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not believe this is solvable with Lambert W. There are generalizations of the Lambert W which may solve this. But they are essentially glorified numerical methods hiding underneath fancy algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, I give an answer for solutions in the reals.

$$x^{y^z}=z$$
$$x^{\left(y^z\right)}=z$$
$$e^{\ln(x)e^{\ln(y)z}}=z$$

Your equation is an equation of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). It's an algebraic equation in dependence of $e^{\ln(x)e^{\ln(y)z}}$ and $z$. Because the terms $e^{\ln(x)e^{\ln(y)z}},z$ are algebraically independent, we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $z$ by only elementary operations (means elementary functions).
I don't know if the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

Your equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W but in terms of Hyper Lambert W.

$$\ln(x)e^{\ln(y)z}=\ln(z)$$
$z\to e^t$:
$$\ln(x)e^{\ln(y)e^t}=t$$
$$\ln(x)=te^{-\ln(y)e^t}$$
$$te^{-\ln(y)e^t}=\ln(x)$$

This equation can be solved by Hyper Lambert W:

$$G(-\ln(y);t)=\ln(x)$$
$$t=HW(-\ln(y);\ln(x))$$
$$z=e^{HW(-\ln(y);\ln(x))}$$

So we have a closed form for $z$, and the representations of Hyper Lambert W give some hints for calculating $z$.

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

Answer (score 1):

**Series solution:**

$\def\B{\operatorname B}$

Using $\ln(x)=a,\ln(y)=b$ and [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) we get a series for “Hyper Lambert W”

$$x^{y^z}=e^{ae^{bz}}=z\implies z=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}e^{ane^{bz}}\right|_{z=0}$$

$e^y$ series:

$$\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(e^{ane^{bz}})\right|_{z=0}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(an)^m}{m!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}e^{mbz}\right|_{z=0}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(an)^m (bm)^{n-1}}{m!}$$

and finally [Bell B$_n(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BellB%28n%2Cx%29) polynomials to get:

$$\boxed{e^{ae^{bz}}=z=1+\frac1b\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(ae^b)^n}{nn!}\B_n(b n)=\frac1b\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(b e^a)^n}{n!}\B_{n-1}(an)}$$

[**Shown**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28-glaisher+e%5E%28-eulergamma+x%29%29-x%2Cx%3D1%2Bsum%5B%28-glaisher%29%5Em%2F%28m%21+%28-eulergamma+m%29%29+e%5E%28-eulergamma+m%29+BellB%28m%2C-eulergamma+m%29%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C30%7D%5D) [**here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28-glaisher+e%5E-%28eulergamma+x%29%29-x%2Cx%3DN%5Bsum%5B%28-eulergamma%29%5E%28n-1%29%2Fn%21+e%5E%28-glaisher+n%29+BellB%28n-1%2C-glaisher+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D%2C10%5D)

**Experimental:**

A [contour integral representation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials#Properties) is:

> $$\B_n(x)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{e^{x(e^t-1)}}{t^{n+1}}dt$$

There are no integral bounds and I have little experience with contour integrals. In case switching the contour integral and sum works:

$$e^{ae^{bz}}=z\mathop=^?1+\frac i{2\pi b}\oint\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{ae^{be^t}}t\right)}tdt\mathop=^?\frac i{2\pi b}\oint\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{be^{ae^t}}t\right)}tdt$$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198421/two-kind-of-equations-involving-natural-log-and-exponentiation/1202225#1202225)

Comment: Why unaccept this answer? Perhaps see Graviton’s comment.