# How do I solve $x^{4^x}=4$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

My friend showed me this problem from Twitter and I am struggling to solve it. I see that I can manipulate it into several equations (some of which I'll insert below), but none seem to be any progress and I feel like I need a different approach. How do I solve this problem?

$$2x\ln\left(2\right)+\ln\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)=\ln\left(\ln2\right)+\ln\left(2\right)$$

$$2^{2x-1}\ln x=\ln2$$

Comment: I guess this must be solved numerically. Not sure whether Lambert-W helps here.

Comment: The numerical value is $$1.2694154073097922799864\cdots $$

Comment: "*My friend showed me this problem from twitter*"  To emphasize... just because a problem can be easily stated does not imply that it can be easily *solved*.  There are plenty of problems written like this for which we simply do not have the language or tools developed to express the answer in any cleaner way than just saying the answer is "*the answer*" or using numerical methods to approximate the final value.

Comment: @JMoravitz I know this but I was hoping that there would exist a clean solution.

Comment: If you can't think of one, that usually means there isn't one.

Comment: Lambert W itself will not solve this.

Comment: Possibly interesting: $x^{4^x}=4$ implies $4^{4^{-x}}=x$ (take base $4$ logs of both sides, then divide by $4^x, \; \ldots),$ then which in turn implies $4^{4^{-\left(4^{4^{-x}}\right)}}=x,$ which in turn implies $\ldots$ This suggests a possible iterative approximation method, namely begin with a rough approximation such as $x= 1.3$ at which to evaluate $4^{4^{-x}},$ giving a new and hopefully closer approximation $1.25690619$ to plug into $4^{4^{-x}},$ giving a new and hopefully closer approximation $1.27472374, \; \ldots$ Doing this 6 more times gives (to $6$ decimal places) $1.269444.$

Comment: You can use the Newtonian numerical method for approximation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\def\B{\operatorname B}$

$$x^{4^x}=4\iff 4^{4^{-x}}=e^{\ln(4)e^{-\ln(4)x}}=x$$

Now use the [Bell polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) and

> [How to solve $x^{y^z}=z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652764/how-to-solve-xyz-z/4653705#4653705):
> $$e^{ae^{bz}}=z=1+\frac1b\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(ae^b)^n}{nn!}\B_n(b n)$$

with $a=-b=\ln(4)$. The other formula in the post diverges, but the above one works. Therefore:

$$\bbox[4px,border: 4px ridge skyblue]{x^{4^x}=4\iff x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln^{n-1}(\sqrt2)}{4nn!}\B_n(-n\ln(4))}$$

which [matches](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=RealDigits%5B1-sum%5B%28ln%28%E2%88%9A2%29%29%5E%28n-1%29%2F%28+4+n+n%21%29+BellB%28n%2C-n+ln%284%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C90%7D%5D%2C10%5D) the digits from @Peter’s comment

Comment: $10,000$ reputation at last.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations for thé 10k and for thé answer

Comment: If wanted, there is an integral representation

Answer (score 2):

When you properly wrote $$2^{(2x-1)}\log( x)=\log(2)$$ you made the function much more linear than the original one and this is very good for any root finding method.

By inspection, you know the the solution is much closer to $1$ than to $2$. So, without resorting to numerical method, make a series expansion around $x=1$, truncate to some order (here, I used the expansion to $O((x-1)^5)$) and use power series reversion to get
$$x=1+\frac{L}{2}+\frac{L^2}{8}-\frac{23 L^3}{48}-\frac{143
   L^4}{384}+\frac{29 L^5}{48}+L^6-\frac{4
   L^7}{3}+O\left(L^{8}\right)$$ where $L=\log(2)$.

This would give $x=1.266171$ which is not fantastic.

But we can make it up to any order and get better and better results. For example, expanding to $O((x-1)^{15})$ the result would be $\color{red}{1.269}36$

We could do it simpler using, instead of Taylor series, simple Padé approximant. A very simple one is
$$2^{(2x-1)}\log( x)\sim  P_2=\frac{2 (x-1)+\frac{32 L^3-24 L^2-4 L-1 }{(24 L^2-12
   L-1)}(x-1)^2 } {1-\frac{32 L^3-24 L^2+6 L+1}{(24 L^2-12 L-1)} (x-1)+\frac{96 L^4-96 L^3+36 L^2+12 L-1}{6 \left(24 L^2-12 L-1\right)}(x-1)^2 }$$ whose error is $\frac{88}{101} (x-1)^5$.

Now writing
$$\text{rhs}=L$$ we have an *approximate* solution at the price of a simple quadratic equation  in $(x-1)$. This would give $x=1.27011$.

Using $P_3$ (whose error is  $\frac{3}{106} (x-1)^7$ ) would require the solution of a cubic equation in $(x-1)$. This would give $x=\color{red}{1.26941}63$.

Answer (score 1):

One to approach this is to let $y=4^x$. That's a nice exponential curve that you can plot easily enough on any graph plotter.

That leaves you with $x^y=4$

Taking logarithms gives you $y \ln x=\ln 4$ or $y=\frac{\ln 4}{\ln x}$. Not so nice, but again, it's a curve that you can plot.

Where the two curves intersect will be the solution to your question.

[image]

It's not an algebraic method, but it gives you some insight into what's going on.

Comment: Your $4^x=\frac{\ln4}{\ln x}$ can be reduced to $\log_4{x}=4^{-x}$ or, if you like, $\log_x{4}=4^x$, keeping $f$ the same.